# mobile browser refuses to scroll to # anchor inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, mobile, anchor

I have a mobile web site with of a fixed header (divs) and below an iframe in which a page from a different domain is being displayed.

As I wanted a specific area of the page to be displayed inside the iframe after loading I used a pre exsiting #anchor located in the external page by defining the iframe's src with the intended domain of the page + # and the name of the anchor. 
It works perfectly on all desktop browsers (in that the page is displayed inside the iframe with the correct line, where the anchor is, at the top of the iframe window), but for some reason when loading the page in a mobile browser (dolphin/Nexus S browser) it doesn't work and all I get is the page inside the iframe as if no anchor was ever defined.. Just the first line of the page at the top of the iframe window...
Any idea why it happens and how to fix it?

Thanks,

Ran.

Comment: To my knowledge, scrolling in an iframe is currently poorly supported in mobile browsers (much less jump to anchor positions). Please correct me if I'm mistaken though.

Comment: is your code working fine with desktop browser, if yes, the it would be great if you can share your test code as well.